# Node created inside of a for loop pointing to null?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

ContactList.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      ContactNode headNode = new ContactNode();
      ContactNode traverse = new ContactNode();
      String name;
      String phoneNum;
      String newLineEater;
      
      for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
     System.out.println("Person " + i);
     System.out.println("Enter name:");

      name = scnr.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
      phoneNum = scnr.nextLine();
      ContactNode newNode = new ContactNode(name, phoneNum);
      System.out.println("You entered: " + name + ", " + phoneNum);
      System.out.println();
      
      
      newNode.insertAfter(headNode);
      
      
      
      

      /* Type your code here. */
   
}

   System.out.println("CONTACT LIST");
 traverse = headNode.getNext();
 traverse.printContactNode();

   
   

}
}
```

And then:

```
public class ContactNode{
   
   private String contactName;
   private String contactPhoneNumber;
   private ContactNode nextNodePtr;
   
   public ContactNode(){
      
      contactName = "n/a";
      contactPhoneNumber = "no phone number";
      
   }
   public ContactNode(String contactName, String contactPhoneNumber){
      
      this.contactName = contactName;
      this.contactPhoneNumber = contactPhoneNumber;
      
   }
   
   public String getName(){
      
      return contactName;
      
      
   }
   
   public String getPhoneNumber(){
      
      return contactPhoneNumber;
      
   }
   
   public void printContactNode(){
      
   
         
      System.out.println("Name: " + this.contactName);
      
         
      }
      
    
      
      
      
   
   
   public ContactNode insertAfter(ContactNode prevNode){
      
      
     return this.nextNodePtr = prevNode;
      
      
      
   }
   
   public ContactNode getNext(){
      
      
      return this.nextNodePtr;
      
      
   }
   
}
```

The two class files are posted above.
The error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ContactList.main(ContactList.java:37)

I thought that I could just reference the Node to test if it had pointed to something. It doesn't. Why? I understand that it NEEDS to point to something, but when I created the Nodes, I thought I had linked them together? What am I missing?

I'm trying to understand the fundamentals of linked lists, and any responses would be super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `newNode.insertAfter(headNode);` to insert a node. The definition is simple:

```java
public ContactNode insertAfter(ContactNode prevNode) {
    return this.nextNodePtr = prevNode;
}
```

Let's walk through the execution.

Initial state:

```
.----------.
| headNode |
|   .next ====> null
`----------`
```

After adding a person (the new node is `this` in your `insertAfter` method; `headNode` is `prevNode` in the method):

```
.----------.   .----------.
| Person 1 |   | headNode |
|   .next ====>|   .next ====> null
`----------`   `----------`
```

We can actually stop here; if you add more people, they'll just point to `headNode` in tandem as Person 1 does, but `headNode` will always point to `null`.

Next you do:

```java
traverse = headNode.getNext();
 traverse.printContactNode();
```

Here, `traverse` is `null`, so `null.printContactNode();` crashes the program.

---

To build a linked list, the normal strategy is one of a few options:

- Keep your `insertAfter` method as-is and build the list in reverse starting with the tail, but set the `headNode = newNode` at the end of your loop so you don't lose track of your nodes.

  The issue with this approach is that your first `headNode` is a dummy node, so you'll want to make sure to avoid it getting into your actual data node list by starting it out as `null` and then checking whether it's `null` or not before calling `insertAfter`. This should make it clear that `insertAfter` is really better named as `insertBefore`!
- Traverse the whole chain of nodes at every addition in O(n). This lets you keep your head as-is, but you'll need to add a loop and change the logic in `insertAfter` -- maybe rename it `insertAtEnd`.
- Keep a `tail` reference and use it to append to the list in O(1). Probably the best approach but requires adding another property to your `ContactList` class.